NVMe SSD showing up as Disk 1 when SATA HDD is connected?
When I plug a regular HDD to my computer's SATA, the NVMe SSD where Windows is installed becomes Disk 1 and the new HDD becomes Disk 0.
Now I know this does not affect performance or anything but I would very much still like to correct the order just to not make things confusing if ever I need to do stuff with the drives later down the road.
There are no other drives connected via SATA, just the new hard drive.
Ice checked the BIOS but I don't see any way of reordering them there.

First, the order in which the BIOS/UEFI sees the disks may not be
the same as that of Windows.
Second, the order of the disks in Windows is fixed
by their type and connection within the computer case.
The ordering rules are :

Fixed disks are enumerated before removable ones
SATA disks are numbered before NVMe
SATA disks are numbered by the port number where they are plugged in
Other disks are given numbers by a Plug and Play system, basically by
the order in which they are found
Formatted disks are enumerated in a more regular manner than
unformatted ones.

This means that the order you see is unchangeable : The SATA disk
will always be enumerated first as Disk0, and the NVMe disk will
become Disk1 once the SATA disk is plugged in.
See this old Microsoft article which is still basically correct today:
Disk drive numbers may not correspond to the SATA channel numbers when you install Windows on a computer that has multiple SATA or RAID disks.
Although this article is more concerned with disk numbers on a new
computer with unformatted disks, it contains useful information.
